# cuda kernel parameter

Tags: cuda

say I have a cuda kernel

```
__global__ foo (int a, int b)
{
    ... ...
}
```

where a and b are stored. Does this takes register space for each thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this doesn't take register space for each thread, instead `a` and `b` are allocated once in a constant space - a read only space - from which all thread can read.

Note that this space is cached by constant registers and shared by all threads:

> A read-only constant cache that is
>   shared by all scalar processor cores
>   and speeds up reads from the constant
>   memory space, which is a read-only
>   region of device memory [PTX ISA Version 2.1 Chapter 3].

Comment: I am guessing that at least when you modify the parameters in your code, they will be copied to registers. Also, registers might be faster than constant memory still, so maybe the copy happens no matter what. Someone should check the generated assembly.